# Proof of Taylor's Formula (Section 4.4) of Hoffman, Kunze, Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

[find the theorem and its proof here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh9sd.png)

First, using the binomial expansion, he writes an expression (say, $A$) for $x^m$. Next, he constructs the polynomial f, applies the operator $D^k$ to f, and gets an expression. With this expression, he writes an alternative form of the summation stated in the theorem. In the last step, the claim is that the expression (say, $B$) to the right of $\sum_{m}a^m$, is equal to $A$. I acknowledge that the expressions inside the sum symbols in $A$ and $B$ are equal. My problem is the following:

**In $A$, the summation is up to m, whereas in $B$, it is up to n.**

By the way, the writer does not emphasize where the summation goes to, so most probably what matters is the expression inside the summation, but I could not get why.

Comment: The summation is up to the degree of the polynomial. $x^m$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, whereas $\sum_{m=0}^n a_mx^m$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. You can of course continue to differentiate after $m$ or $n$, but note that for $p>q$, $D^p(x^q)=0$.

Comment: Then in the last step, we have $\sum_{m=0}^na_m\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(D^kx^m)}{k!}(c)(x-c)^k$, but since $k<=m$, the summation $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(D^kx^m)}{k!}(c)(x-c)^k$ makes sense for the values of k=0,..,m. Thus, we get $x^m$. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: Yes. At the beginning of this step, the double sum is to be read $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{m=0}^n$, then you exchange the sums, then the inner sum is still $\sum_{k=0}^n$, but the terms are zero after $k=m$, so it's equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^m$.